# awk not printing OFS with pipe or text file

Tags: awk

I am on ubuntu, please help what I am doing wrong

```
$ echo "hello there" | awk -v OFS=";" '{print $0 $1 $2}'
hello therehellothere
$ echo "hello there" | awk 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {print $0 $1 $2}'
hello therehellothere
$ awk 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {print $0 $1 $2}' hello.txt
hello therehellothere
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

print needs `,` to separate each output variables/values:

```
$ echo "hello there" | awk -v OFS=";" '{print $0,$1,$2}'
#=> hello there;hello;there
$ echo "hello there" | awk 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {print $0,$1,$2}'
#=> hello there,hello,there
```

space  is to simply concatenate each strings/variables.
It's a mistake to use space when you needed OFS, but for some needs it's handy.